# Is there a way to import color schemes from JetBrains CLion into Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, clion

I have and am fond of the color schemes in JetBrains CLion, but noticed that Android Studio doesn't have many of them (Default and Darcula)

Is there a way to import color schemes from CLion into Android Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export in `Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Export`, Import from `Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Import Scheme`.

However, I want to know if you have forgotten to install the [Material Theme UI](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui) plugin in your Android Studio?

Comment: I don't have the Material Theme UI plugin installed, but I exported/imported the theme and it works perfectly.